# Start the animation of something when app starts

Tags: swift

I am trying to learn Swift. I currently have a button that plays an animation but I want to have the animation start immediately after the app loads.  How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your animation on the `viewDidApear` method, while will be called after your `viewDidLoad` method.

For example

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(2, animations: {
            //do what ever here
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very specific so I'm not sure if this answers your question.

When your iOS application starts, there is usually a View Controller that gets rendered on the screen as your main entry point. This can be changed in in your AppDelegate.swift

Now, let's assume that in your application, a view controller named **WelcomeViewController** is the first page and you have your button along with the rest of your logic in it. Every view controller has certain functions that you can override and use. For example:

viewDidLoad

viewDidAppear

viewWillAppear

viewWillDisappear

the names are self-explanatory so I'm sure you can guess what they do. In your case, just override viewDidAppear and start your animation in there.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    ...
}
```